# VBA Excel .Range syntax and comparators

Tags: vba, excel, range

first post here sorry if the formatting is really bad. Need some help with a VBA Excel file I'm working on. The code is below and a description underneath. Any help would be appreciated

```
Sub Main()

' Declare all variables    
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date
Dim prod As String
Dim Add As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
Dim ProdString As String

'Calculate the number of rows in the sheet, then run a for loop for every row.
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To LastRow
y = x

'concatenate the current row number (x) and third column to a string (prod string), then check to see what letter is in that cell.  
'Assign a letter to concatenate with variable 'x' to String Prod for the .Range Function

ProdString = x & 3
**If Range(ProdString).Value = "I" Then** 
    prod = "K"
ElseIf Application.ActiveSheet.Range(ProdString).Value = "E" Then
    prod = "L"
ElseIf Application.ActiveSheet.Range(ProdString).Value = "O" Then
    prod = "M"
ElseIf Application.ActiveSheet.Range(ProdString).Value = "Q" Then
    prod = "N"
Else: prod = "O"
End If

' Add two numbers together in two different cells and assign to the second cell
var1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D" & x).Value
var2 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("prod" & x).Value
Add = var1 + var2
Application.ActiveSheet.Range("prod" & x).Value = Add


'While Loop to go through applicable date range from starting date to end date and add to those columns
Do While True

Date1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range(y, 6).Value
Date2 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range(y + 1, 6).Value
If Application.ActiveSheet.Range(y, 7).Value <> Application.ActiveSheet.Range(y + 1, 7) Then Exit Do
If Date1 < Date2 Then Exit Do

var1 = Range("D" & x).Value
var2 = Range("prod" & y).Value
Add = var1 + var2
Range("prod" & y).Value = Add
y = y + 1

Loop

Next x
End Sub
```

The Excel file I'm working with is one workbook, on one sheet with 10k rows and 15 columns. I'm trying to add a number in one column to another based on dates. But the current issue I'm having  is just trying to figure out the Bolded .Range function and why it won't work. I've tried preceding it with the specific workbook and pagename but I get global scope errors when I do. I just want to compare what is inside the cell at the specified range, and if it is a certain string assign a value to a different string value.
Thanks.

Comment: You are looking at PodString, which is a String, while trying to use that as a Range.  You will need to define the range you want to work in.  Example, if PodString = fdsa, then Range("fdsa") would error out; if PodString were a range and = Range("A2:B2"), then Range(PodString) = Range("A2:B2").

Comment: Also when you start your sub, you declared `X` but never gave it a value. Why even use `x`?  What do you mean by `Range(podString)`? That's going to be a single number, no? Like `Range(3)`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I have an answer going with a more significant list of questions... hoping to get some code going after the intent is made more clear.  This is... kind of rough to extrapolate intent of variables.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the syntax wrong. What is the correct method to call to select what's inside a cell? Cell or Range? Can I use variables in the parameter definitions of these two methods, and if so how? To start I just want to select a cell based on a variable. Then use what ever is in that cell for other values. Should I even be using vba or just the excel built in functions instead?

Answer (score 0):

Planning to update with code, once I can figure out what is happening...

---

Trying to build on my comment for you, using what I feel I can interpret from your code.

I believe you're trying to loop through a range, though I am having trouble trying to place your x and y variables, based on where they are used.  I will try to deduce... assuming that you're checking through ProdString = x & 3 to mean the third row, x is your column.  I am seeing comparisons for the specific string in I3 (Cells(3,9)), E3 (Cells(3,5)), O3 (Cells(3,15)), and Q3 (Cells(3,17)).

I'm not seeing what ProdString is supposed to be... what are you comparing?

I imagine you want something like (this is not sufficient code atm):

```
Dim ProdString as String, prod as String, x as Integer

ProdString = Cells(3,prod).Value

If Cells(3,9).Value=ProdString Then
    prod = Cells(3,11).Value 'Getting lost at why prod us being used as such
    Else
    End If
```

I can't figure out what you're trying to add, since the Column = x, but you're using ranges later such as Range("D" & x).

---

Edit:

After getting some clarification to my questions, I would have the following changes to your code (only bringing in the items I need to correct for the Range error:

```
Dim prod as String, x as Integer

For x = 2 to LastRow

    If Cells(x,3).Value = "I" Then
        prod = "K"
        Else 'Only showing the one option to shorten my response
        End If

Next x
```

Note that ProdString is removed.  As written, it had no value.  The String of x&3 is *not* a range, and cannot be used as a range, e.g., Range(ProdString).  If you want to loop through rows of a column, you can ignore using Range() and go via Cells() to make a simple approach.

Specific to what is in this code, you are saying that the Value held within the cell being looped through has the value "I".  Without seeing the data, I can only assume that you are in fact only looking for the value "I", though the use of **prod** makes me think this is wrong.  I suspect you are trying to capture the column name/number, so you will need to look at that because if you're locked to column 3 and looping through rows, you would never see column "I".  I would recommend the following change for replacing **prod**:

```
Dim x as Integer, prod as Integer

For x = 2 to LastRow

    If Cells(x,3).Value = "I" Then 'Ensure that this is truly supposed to be a value of I in the cell
        prod=Cells(x,11).Value
        Cells(x,11).Formula=Cells(x,4).Value+prod 'It looks like you're overwriting the cell in row x, column 11
        Else 
        End If

Next x
```

Let me know if this clears anything up.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my code. I rushed to put it up and realized I had taken out some parts that were important. the point of the code is to do a for loop for every row, add a value in one row to another column of the same row depending on another value. Then to do a while loop and keep adding that number in the x row to subsequent y rows beneath it. If the accounts don't match or the dates are out of sync then exit the while loop and keep going with the x for loop. Hopefully that clears up some confusion. My main concern is just getting the .Range function to work.

Comment: @JGenchi Then the initial comment would stand (to your post).  You don't have ProdString qualified as a range, and it is not a range that you are using.  I will update my Answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @JGenchi Please see what I have below the Edit... I have corrected for your Range issue, but as mentioned, you might run into more issues with your chosen approach.